# Unable to remove on hover background colour from mat-chip

Tags: html, css, angular

i need to remove the on hover background colour to transparent on hovering.

[Price chip without hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZQo0.png)

[Price chip with hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpBg.png)

**HTML** :-

```
<div>
    <mat-chip-list>
       <mat-chip class="price-filter">Price <svg width="24" 
          height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" class=" 
          NMm5M"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5H7z"></path></svg> 
       </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
</div>
```

**CSS** :-

```
.price-filter{
border: solid;
border-color: #dad5d5;
border-width: thin;
background-color: transparent;
cursor:pointer;
color: var(--primary) !important;
}

.price-filter > mat-icon {
background-color: transparent;
opacity: 1;
}

.NMm5M {
fill: var(--primary) !important;
position: relative;
left: 11px;
}

.price-filter:hover{
background-color: transparent !important;
 }
```

i want to remove the grey colour on hover as shown in the screenshot in second link.

Comment: write on codepen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why simple don't change in the class `price-filter` the hover rule?

like:

```
.price-filter:hover{background-color:inherit!important;} // or want you want.
```

EDIT after see live version:

The problem is that code:

```
.mat-chip.mat-standard-chip::after {
    background: #0000;
}
```

if you change that to trasparent all work how you want.

Comment: i had tried the same but on hover the grey colour shows up. i want to make it transparent which doesn't work.

Comment: Like own hover there shouldn't be any transition.

Comment: Have you a live version?

Comment: try to change `.mat-chip:hover`  to `.price-filter:hover` how write.  and please post a live version because i can't reproduce your code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqnxcc?file=src/styles.css

Comment: yes it's working , but when i click on it i get the same gray colour

Comment: add `disableRipple` to `<mat-chip>`

Answer (score 1):

**This solved my problem**

```
.mat-chip.mat-standard-chip::after {
  background: none !important;  // color that you want on hover
}
```